# maximize expected value of a Heaviside function

Tags: probability, optimization, parameter-estimation

$X$ is a random variable and a cost function is $f(x;c)$ where $c$ is the parameter to be estimated.

Then how to find $c$ to maximize $E_x[H(f(x;c))]$, where H is Heaviside unit step function.

Comment: The expected value of an indicator function (_i.e._ Heaviside function) is the probability of that event. So $\mathbb{E}[H(f(X;c))]=\mathbb{P}[f(X;c)\geq0]$. More can’t be said without knowing about your function $f$ and the distribution of $X$. Try adding some context to your question.